# Memcached Stores Data but Returns Nothing...?

Tags: cakephp, memcached

I have this CakePHP array that is updated periodically (an hour or so) and stored into memcached. Recently, I changed the structure of the array so it's easier to work with in a view but I still cache it with the same name / key. However, I'm running into this problem where once in a while, the view goes screwy (the data in the array goes into an unordered list, and if the array returns empty, it's set to not show anything).

The strange thing though is that in my controller code, I have logic like (somewhat-pseudo code):

```
$list_array = array();
if(cache_read('key', 'controller_name')) {
     $list_array = &cache_read('key', 'controller_name');
}
else {
     $list_array = $this->Model->function_that_generates_the_same_array();
     cache_write('key', $list_array, 'controller_name');
}
```

So regardless, the array should be populated.

The only thing that has changed is the structure of the array, but I'm not sure whether it's something with Memcached that's wrong, or my code. I'm leaning towards memcached being the issue because I've never had this issue before prior to the change.

Any thoughts? Insights? I'm rather new to memcached so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually connecting to your memcached server and validating what is stored there and returned?

Try (change localhost to your memcached server):

```
telnet localhost 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
get key
```

Comment: if that works then I doubt the issue would be with memcached.  Would just do a simple test though... just make a php page that connects to memcached, gets the value and dumps it.  If that works, fine then there would be something else that is the issue.